# Using Facebook as single signon

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I am developing an mvc.net application and would like to use Facebook Connect as single signon, but do I need to create a Facebook application from within their interface, or can I use the login features without creating an application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is required that you register your application through Facebook even just for doing single sign-on.  This is mentioned in their [instructuctions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login).

"The JavaScript SDK requires that you register your application with Facebook to get an app id for your site."

I do know that it is required if you are doing any server-side work as well.